# How to add Html Audio element using c# code

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

On an asp button's onClick event, I want to play a song on client. I have written the following code for doing so..

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl myAudio = new HtmlGenericControl("audio");
    myAudio.Attributes.Add("autoplay", "true");
    myAudio.Attributes.Add("hidden", "true");
    myAudio.Attributes.Add("src", Server.MapPath("~/Songs/") + "1.wav");
    myDivTag.Controls.Add(myAudio);
}
```

The Html is as follows :

```
<div id="myDivTag" runat="server"></div>
```

But even after the code is executed the `div` tag remains empty, And the song is not played. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but I can't comment. Have you tried if the path is correct?
Is the ASP.NET-Control needed? How about http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp?

Code of it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your html like this

```
<div runat="server" id="myDivTag">
    <audio autoplay runat="server" id="myaudio">
        <source src="" runat="server" type="audio/mpeg">
        <p>If you can read this, your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
    </audio>
</div>
```

and your button click event like this

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myaudio.Src = "~/new.mp3";
}
```

music playing in backend. so you can not pause music or stop it.

if you pause your music then some custom logic needed.